# Calling a servlet located in a package from a jsp located in a directory

Tags: jsp, servlets, refresh

I have a servlet called 'addpicture' located in a package called 'AdminClasses' and a JSP page called 'add_picture' located inside a folder called 'AdminPages'.

Now, I want to call the servlet from this jsp page. But, since the jsp page is inside that folder, it throws error as resource not available . When I move the JSP page to the main web pages folder, it works fine. But, I dont wanna do it cause all my adminpages are in the 'adminPages' folder and if I move them, it will be a mess. So, is there any way to call this servlet from that jsp page while its inside the adminPages folder?

Help will be deeply appreciated and while you at it can you also tell me how to resolve the issue of refresh; i.e. when I refresh the page the form gets resubmitted.

Comment: A suggestion...If you write the question with proper punctuation marks, paragraphs and with correct capitalization of letters, it makes the question readable and you will only be benefited, as many people will be able to read it and you will end up getting more number of answers.

Comment: A possible solution: `<form method="POST" action="../addPicServelet">`. Please refer to a Servlet tutorial like [SO Servlet wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). Also, this problem may happen in NetBeans, Eclipse, JDeveloper or another IDE, even developing using plain text editors.

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet should have an URL associated to it, which should be defined in your [**web.xml**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html) file with a [**servlet-mapping**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html).

From the JSP you have to use the URL of the servlet in your [**form action**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp), for example. It doesn't matter if the servlet class is in other package.

Comment: here is my mapping web.xml code for the addPicture           servlet   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>addPicServelet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>adminClasses.addPicServelet</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>                                                            <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>addPicServelet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/addPicServelet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>                                              and calling it with  <form action="addPicServelet"  name="frmaddpicture" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" >